# Adding an object from another class to SelectListItem?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, razorengine, selectlistitem

Im wondering how SelectListItem works, kinda new at this. Been searching the net for a tutorial but  nothing i could find made anny sense to me.

I have a controller and a method that returns a List of objects. I also have a ListModel class that has a List of SelectListItem wich is implemented in a `@html.DropDownList` in the View. Im trying to add the method from the controller to the SelectListItem-List but it wont work because `List<MyClass>` cannot be converted to `List<SelectListItem>`. However if i change `List<MyClass>` to `List<SelectListItem>` some values vill be selectable in the `@html.DropDownList` but i don't want to Display the values, i want to be able to select the method from the controller and then the method runs and returns the result.

The main idea is that when the end user select the item in the DropDownList the Method in the controller will run and display the data.

Would very much appreciate some input on this subject.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
List<MyClass> class = new List<MyClass>();
//populate class  here

//put the objects in selectlist itme list, can filter if want specific element
List<SelectListItem> list = class.Select(new SelectListItem{value = x.Valueprop, Text = x.textProp});
```